# How do I print numbers in a different method?

Tags: java

How do I make sure the numbers are printed?
=>          output += String.format("The numbers %d and %d are a Primetwin", number1, number2);
the contents of number1 and number2 are not known within the method giveResultPrimeTwin

Suggestions?

```
package ui;
import domein.MyNumbers;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeTwinApplication {
    

    
    public static void main (String args[]  )
    {
        int number1, number2;
        
        PrimeTwinApplication numbers = new  PrimeTwinApplication ();
        number1 = numbers.inputNumber("Give a number:");
        number1 = numbers.inputNumber("Give a number:");
        
        MyNumbers mg = new MyNumbers (number1, number2);

        System.out.printf(numbers.giveResultPrimeTwin(mg));
        
            }
    
    private int inputNumber (String question)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int number;
        System.out.print(question);
        number= input.nextInt();
        
        return number;
    }
    
    private String giveResultPrimeTwin(MyNumbers mg)
    {

        
        String output = "";
       
    
        if (mg.isPrimeTwin() == true)
            output += String.format("The numbers %d and %d are a Primetwin", number1, number2);

        
        else
        output += String.format("The numbers %d and %d are not a Primetwin", number1, number2);


        
        return output;

        
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're putting `number1` and `number2` inside an instance of something called `MyNumbers`. So presumably you can get them back of out it.

Comment: You should move `int number1, number2;` before the `main` method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make number1 and number 2 instance properties of PrimeTwinApplication class. Then you can use it anywhere in PrimeTwinApplication functions.

```
package ui;
import domein.MyNumbers;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeTwinApplication {
    int number1;
    int number2;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        PrimeTwinApplication numbers = new PrimeTwinApplication();
        numbers.number1 = numbers.inputNumber("Give a number:");
        numbers.number2 = numbers.inputNumber("Give a number:");
        
        MyNumbers mg = new MyNumbers(numbers.number1, numbers.number2);

        System.out.printf(numbers.giveResultPrimeTwin(mg)); 
    }
    
    private int inputNumber(String question)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        System.out.print(question);
        number= input.nextInt();
        
        return number;
    }
    
    private String giveResultPrimeTwin(MyNumbers mg)
    {
        String output = "";
    
        if (mg.isPrimeTwin() == true)
            output += String.format("The numbers %d and %d are a Primetwin", number1, number2);
        else
            output += String.format("The numbers %d and %d are not a Primetwin", number1, number2);
        
        return output;
    }
```